# Material-ui don't change the style when the MenuItem has selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently, I styled `background-color: red;` if the `MenuItem` that has `selected={true}`

and if I hover the option, `MenuItem` `background-color` will change to `green`.

But when I hover over the `MenuItem` that has `selected={true}`, the `background-color` will be `light-blue` which is mui default.

I'd like to keep `background-color: red;` for `MenuItem` that has `selected={true}` even if this component get hovered over.

index.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import MenuList from "@mui/material/MenuList";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { MenuItem } from "./styles";

export default function MenuListComposition() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Paper>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuItem selected={true}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Paper>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { default as MuiMenuItem } from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

export const MenuItem = styled(MuiMenuItem)`
  color: blue;
  padding: 20px;

  &.Mui-selected {
    background-color: red;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, just need to add the `&.Mui-selected:hover` to overwrite the default background color.

```
export const MenuItem = styled(MuiMenuItem)`
  color: blue;
  padding: 20px;

  &.Mui-selected {
    background-color: red;
  }

  // Add this
  &.Mui-selected:hover{ 
    background-color: red;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-monad-qfb9zu?file=/demo.js)